# VT1001 talking thermostat has started saying “two sixty four”

Tags: heating, thermostat

I have a energy star rated VT1001 talking thermostat installed sometime in the early to mid 2000s.  This morning it began to periodicall speak the words “two sixty four” (264). I cannot find anything to explain to me what this means.  I have located and obtained a user manual for a smilar thermostat from the same manufacturer but this gives no explanation.

When this occurs then the light button no longer iluminates the lcd display.  However, pressing the report button does illuminate the display and immediately produces the phrase 264 as discribed above.

Can anyone here tell me what this message means?

Comment: It seems that the VT1001 is an older model and a quick Google search doesn't turn up a manual for it. It did give me their web-site which has a [Contact Us](http://www.smartwaysolutions.com/contact.asp) link.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try contacting them.  I posted here in the hope that someone might know the answer from past experience with the unit.  My own take on it is that likely I need a replacement.

Comment: Are there mysterious submarines lurking off the coast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the unit.   I inferred that the spoken numbers were likely the firmware version and conveyed no additional information.  There are newer units on the market which are trivial to install and which have the same or better features that cost (2018) in the range of $50-$75CAD ($35-$55USD).

Answer (score 1):

Probably not much help two years later but I was able to fix mine by cleaning the contacts on the circuit board with isopropyl alcohol for the up/down and light buttons. Seems it gets gummed up after years of use.  Of course, take the batteries out before cleaning it.

Comment: The OP was asking for the meaning of the code "264" so this really doesn't answer the question.  I hope the OP hasn't had to listen to the thermostat talking for 2.75 years.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: @JACK This answer might be very helpful to someone who's having the same (or similar) problem and just got here....

Comment: @GregNickoloff I agree. That's why I commented and accepted the answer and didn't DV or delete.