# Talking Thermostat also saying "two sixty four"

Tags: thermostat

This has been [asked before](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/125344/vt1001-talking-thermostat-has-started-saying-two-sixty-four) but there wasn't any solution. To top it off, I'm new and I can't ask the OP if he solved his problem. I may have to call him tonight. He's in the next town over. But let's see if anyone knows what the problem is.

Talking Thermostat VT1001 out of the blue starts saying "two sixty four". We had the fan circulating for a few days and all was well. Then the "two sixty four" started. So I shut the fan off. It's still doing it with the fan off.

Really unnerving when you're the only one in the house. Help!

Comment: Is the light button stuck down? Holding that button for seven seconds makes the unit read out it's current software version, I wonder if 264 is the software version you have.

Comment: A photo of the unit and the display would be helpful.

Comment: Any fix? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what that error code means, but you can reset this unit by pressing and holding both the "Reset" button and the "No" button simultaneously for at least ten seconds, then pressing the "Run" button.  You'll have to reprogram the thermostat.

My next step would be to replace this with a standard programmable thermostat, the talking thermostat is mostly a marketing gimmick, [it was promoted to HVAC contractors as a device that would generate calls for routine service and maintenance.](http://www.smartwaysolutions.com/pdf/Talking_Thermostat_Handbook_VTXX07.pdf)